# Odata Queries and Date Fields

Tags: rest, filter, date-time

I have a calculated field that contains the logic

```
if(date)
{Yes;}

else
{No;}
```

This works fine for the column's calculation, but I either need to get the result of the calculated field or need to access the date and check if the date is null or not using a REST call.  From what I've gathered, I cannot access calculated fields using OData, and according to this article and my testing, I cannot check for null dates either. Does anyone have any advice on how to proceed here?

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/f20cb779-825f-4261-9623-26551fe5c853/how-to-filter-on-null-dates-via-rest-api?forum=appsforsharepoint

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Log')/items?$filter=Outage eq 'Yes'&$filter=EndDate ne null
```

`Outage eq 'Yes'` works correctly, but I can't seem to filter on EndDate, is there a way around this issue I'm seeing?